# HTML5 pattern not validating

Tags: javascript, html

This is my `input` element. I want it to accept only letters (No numbers or any other characters).

```
<input type="text" name="firstName" pattern="[a-zA-Z]" class="form-control"  id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required>
```

This is my entire partial view.

```
<form method = "post" action = "" ng-controller = "signUpCtrl as signUp">

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" name="firstName" pattern="[a-zA-Z]" class="form-control"  id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="middleName" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Middle Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="middleName" placeholder="Middle Name" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="lastName" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Last Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="dob" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Date of Birth</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="userName" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">User Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" placeholder="User Name" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="confirmPassword" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Confirm Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Email Address</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info submitButton">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

I am using - Google Chrome  50.0.2661.94 (Official Build) m (32-bit)

Comment: what's the problem you are getting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `^[a-zA-Z][^0-9]+$` or `^\w[^\d]+$` instead of `[a-zA-Z]`.

> **Edit :**
>
> If you need to skip symbols also then use :
>
> ```
> ^[a-zA-Z][^0-9-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]+$.
> ```
>
> or
>
> `^[a-zA-Z][^0-9\W]+$ // this will skip all non-word characters.`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='container'>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">

      <form method="post" action="" ng-controller="signUpCtrl as signUp">

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="firstName" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">First Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" name="firstName" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][^0-9]+$" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" required>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="middleName" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Middle Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="middleName" placeholder="Middle Name" required>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="lastName" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Last Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" required>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="dob" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Date of Birth</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dob" placeholder="Date of Birth" required>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="userName" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">User Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" placeholder="User Name" required>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Password</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="confirmPassword" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Confirm Password</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Email Address</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info submitButton">Submit</button>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `^` and `$` are not really necessary. A full match from begin to end is always required. The `+` is necessary though.

Comment: This will accept a letter, then anything other than a digit. The OP said he wants only letters.

Comment: @torazaburo. Yeah some fault of here. ill edit my answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with the following(use this in the input element):

```
ng-pattern="/^[A-Za-z]+$/"
```